# Looping through the range of cells to test the dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a function to check the dates in 'Dt' sheet and return Match or Not Match.

It works fine with when I display my answer in MsgBox, but when I try to do it in one of the spreadsheet loop process goes to the end of the date range.

Can anybody help me out what am I doing wrong here?

---

```
function CheckDates(Month,Day,Year) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dt')
  var sheet = ss.getSheetId()[0];     

  var startRow = 1;
  var endRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var endCol = ss.getLastColumn()

  var Month = "4";
  var Day = "21";
  var Year = "2013";

  var myDate =  new Date(Month + '/' + Day + '/' + Year);
  var dtStr = 1 + myDate.getMonth();
  dtStr = dtStr + '/' + myDate.getDate().toString() + '/' +
    myDate.getFullYear().toString();

   for (var r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++) {        
     var cellValue = ss.getRange(r,1,endRow,endCol).getValue();
     var dt = new Date(cellValue);
     var str = 1 + dt.getMonth(); //getMonth() start with 0
     str = str + '/' + dt.getDate().toString() + '/'+ 
       dt.getFullYear().toString();

       if(str == dtStr) {
         x = "Match"
       } else {
         x = "Not Match"
       }
    }
  return x; 
}
```

---

Comment: Perhaps you can share a doc with us?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for you to approach this. The first is via good old formula's. The second is via a Google Apps Script (GAS). The latter is done when the logic in the formula becomes too complex or too slow.

### Solutions

```
(1) Formula
----------- 
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Dt!A2:A5=DATEVALUE("13/03/2013"),"Match","No Match"))

(2) Google Apps SCript
----------------------
function myCheck(range,year,month,day) {
  var output = [], myDate = new Date(year,month-1,day);

  for(var i in range) {
    var ckDate = new Date(range[i]);
    if(ckDate-myDate === 0) {
      output.push(["Match"]);
    } else {
      output.push(["No Match"]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

### Explained

1. The formula converts the string date to a date value and compares it
   to the range. If one of them is equal, then it will show/display the
   word "Match".
2. The code can be written without API calls. All dates are compared (substracted) and the outcome is pushed into an array and returned.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Looping Through Dates](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdFctM193M3YzUExxZkIzMFY4bmdjUlE&usp=sharing)**

### Remarks to your Code

- Fiddling around with dates in GAS can be quite difficult. Use the
  `Logger.log()` method to capture intermediate results, so that you
  can evaluate them.
- When you declare something, use it; `var sheet` isn't used.
- If you want something to be declared, then do it; `x` isn't explicitly declared.
- I've rearranged your code a bit. See example file. Outcome is reversed to what you wanted....
- See script editor for your original code. I've added `Logger.log()` to see the intermediate results.